# Can't find the page that is using a slug

Tags: pages, slug

I am using Wordpress test site and working on a page where I can display Team members. At some point I was working on two Team pages at the same time, just to compare which style I liked more. Along the way, something got messed up and now the slug "spetsialistid" I want to use is apparently being used to show team archive.

I can see the archive page when i enter the URL, but can't find it anywhere to delete or change it. Nothing in trash. There also isn't an "Edit" option at the top of the page as there is with other pages.

When I change my preferred team page's slug to "spetsialistid", the whole pages changes to display Team Archive instead.

I am fairly new to Wordpress and cannot figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When you register a post type with an archive then the URL gets reserved for the archive of that post type. It can't be deleted. Where are Team Members coming from? Did you register the post type yourself with code? Are you using a plugin, or is it a feature of your theme?

Comment: The website was handed over to me by a colleague, so I'm not sure how she created the original team page that now uses the slug I want to use. 

Team is a feature of my The7 theme. 

Might there be a way to at least change the URL/slug so that I can use it for a page I actually need?

Comment: You would need to ask the theme author. Third party themes are off topic here.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info!